# PHP form validation

Tags: php, css, forms, validation

So I have created a form inside html the code -

```
<form method="post" action="hi.php"> 


    <fieldset>
        <label class="labelone" type="text" />
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
        <label class="email" for="email" />
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <label class="phonenumber" for="phonenumber" />
        <input name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
        <label class="comments" for="comments" />
        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" >
        <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this is the php -

```
<?php



    $emailSubject = 'Test';
    $webMaster = 'Test';



    $name = $_GET['firstname'];
    $email = $_GET['lastname'];
    $message = $_GET['comment'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $firstname <br>
Last Name: $lastname <br>
Message: $comment <br>
EOD;


    $headers = "From: $lastname\r\n";
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);




    $theResults = <<<EOD
<?php 

?>

<?php



    $emailSubject = 'Kent Pest Control Services';
    $webMaster = 'xxxxxxxxxEDITED@gmail.com';



    $name = $_GET['firstname'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $phonenumber = $_GET['phonenumber']
    $message = $_GET['comments'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $firstname <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone Number: $phonenumber <br>
Message: $comments <br>
EOD;
```

When I upload it to my hosting and fill in the php form, and click submit, it goes to a blank screen, and I dont get an email, I have used this before like a year ago, I dont know if the code has changed since then, but I cant get it to work, I hope someone can help. :) I changed the email so people cant email me ;)

Comment: Change your form method from **post** to **get**

Comment: youve pasted a section in twice (it looks like) and put a live email in it

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a `<form>` tag in your HTML.

try this:

```
<form action="yourPHPfile.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="labelone" type="text" />
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
        <label class="email" for="email" />
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <label class="phonenumber" for="phonenumber" />
        <input name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
        <label class="comments" for="comments" />
        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" >
        <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I would use POST, and not GET as you are passing potentially a lot of data through and it would create a very ugly url.

your php file then..

```
<?php

$emailSubject = 'Test';
$webMaster = 'Test';

$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$email = $_POST['lastname'];
$message = $_POST['comments']; // you have the wrong key in your original file (comment)

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $firstname <br>
Last Name: $lastname <br>
Message: $comment <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $lastname\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);


$theResults = <<<EOD

?>
```

other points:
    you should be [validating](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) the email address server side if youre going to do anything else with it, like send back a confirmation etc

Comment: thanks for the answer i all ready had that code i forgot to put it in the text.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this code can resolve you query**

```
<form action="actionname.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="labelone" type="text" />
        <input name="firstname" placeholder="Your firstName"/>
        <label class="labeltwo" type="text" />
        <input name="lastname" placeholder="Your LastName"/>
        <label class="email" for="email" />
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <label class="phonenumber" for="phonenumber" />
        <input name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
        <label class="comments" for="comments" />
        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" >
        <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Now this php code

```
<?php

$emailSubject = 'Test';
$webMaster = $_POST['email']; /* Pass your form email address here */

$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; /* Firstname from form */
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];  /* Lastname from form */
$message = $_POST['comments'];  /* Comment from form */

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $firstname <br>
Last Name: $lastname <br>
Message: $message <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $lastname\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);


$theResults = <<<EOD

?>
```

Comment: Check this for mail in php [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)